# Convert date/time in date only in R

Tags: r, date, time, date-conversion

Tried many options, but failed. Forced to ask here.
I have a date/time in **1/1/2016 0:00** format.

So, I tried

```
start.time <- citi.bike$starttime
head(start.time)
start.date <- strftime(as.Date(start.time), format="%m/%d/%Y")
head(start.date)
```

I do not know why, but my date looks like 
*"01/20/0001" "01/20/0001" "01/20/0001" "01/20/0001" "01/20/0001" "01/20/0001"*.

All days became as "20".

Why?

Comment: Just `as.Date(x, format="%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: Oh, good sir @thelatemail, I spent two hours trying it and you did it in 30 sec. Can you help me with the sec question please? I tried to use lubridate package, searched a lot, but again failed.

Comment: Or use `anytime::anydate(x)` on it. The mission of the [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package is to _just do the right thing_ for date/datetime conversion because most of the time it is somewhat obvious what needs to be done.  It also does it at C++ level so it is pretty quick for large input.

Comment: Thanks, @Dirk Eddelbuettel, I have installed it right now and will try to work with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or `lubridate::dmy_hm("1/1/2016 0:00")`